# 'Quick Look' in Xcode Playground showing memory address instead of object and other strangeness

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This could be an error on my part (likely, since I am new to Swift and Xcode), but when I use the "Quick Look" option in playground, I expect to see the representation of my object, and instead see the following:

[image]

Secondly, if I try to see the contents of an array, it just shows "8 elements" instead of what I would expect to see... a list of elements and their indexes:

[image]

And again, same with dictionaires:

[image]

When I used the playground in earlier versions, it would display things differently in Quick Look. Is this a change since the last version (currently using 6.3.2), or just a setting I am overlooking somewhere?

Comment: Can you please have a look what is selected in the menu : "Debug"->"Debug Workflow"

Comment: It looks like nothing is "selected" -- http://bit.ly/1Id9QE2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug they are working on in 6.3.2

After doing a lot of searching for options, and problems on Google and StackOverflow...I finally logged into the developer forum on Apple's site, and discovered the following question (not sure why it wasn't coming up in my Google search results...perhaps because those forums are 'private').

> This is a known bug -- we're working on a fix.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1139728#1139728